# Percentage sign inside .htaccess mod_rewrite

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, escaping

My server keeps throwing a 404 error when i include a percentage sign(%) inside my mod_rewrite regex. I have searched everywhere with no avail. I am running apache 2.4.4 and have tried the B flag shown below.

```
RewriteRule ^pages/([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z+%'"]+)$ pages/$1.php?search=$2 [B]
```

So when i access pages/animals/cats%20and%20dogs it fails. But works like a charm when i change `([a-zA-Z+%'"]+)` to `(.*)`

Regex  level = toddler, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%20` is matched using `\s` (space) in mod_rewrite. However based on comments below it appears you want to match other non-word characters as well hence it is better to use a `\W`

So change your rule to:

```
RewriteRule ^(pages)/([a-z]+)/([a-z\W]+)$ $1/$2.php?search=$3 [B,L,NC]
```

Comment: Replacing "%" with "\s" still failed when %20 is in the url.
I also need the percentage sign for %2C and %40 (, @)

Comment: You need to understand that `%2C` and `%40` characters etc are encoded before URL lands at Apache. Please see edited answer to match all these cases using `\W`

Comment: Ah i see! Thanks alot, all special characters are working now except for `(%2F, %5C) (/, \)`.

Comment: Oh ok I will investigate that once I get back to my computer in an hour.

Comment: All fixed. I had to append `AllowEncodedSlashes On` to my httpd.conf file. Now all encoded characters are playing along nicely. Thanks anubhava.

Comment: Oh perfect, thanks for letting me know about `AllowEncodedSlashes On`

Comment: \W is used in the regex, but the text still says \s. Also a link to the documentation might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, I have added reason of using `\W` in answer.